# Resource Folder VS Resx File

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2008, c#-3.0

First, please note I am a Java developer, started C# just few weeks back. Here is my question, it is about Visual Studio IDE.

I am using visual studio ide 2008 to create C# projects. I opened a new windows application, added a picture box to the form and now ready to add an image to it. I clicked the small black arrow button in picture box and it opens a dialog where we can put images.

Now, the question comes. In my c# book, they add images using the first option "Local Resource". Anyway, since I have to add number of images, I selected the "Project Resource File" and added all the images to the folder at once. Now I am working smooth without any issue. But, I can see the "Form.resx" file is empty (in my book, they show that file contains all the image files).

I want to know whether what I have done is correct or not. Even though that file is empty, no errors in the program anyway. I don't know whether any issue will occur after the distribution, like missing resources (In Java it normally happens unless otherwise you put all the resources into a new 'Package' inside the project. That's one of reasons I selected the second option when adding the images).  Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your resources will be in a file called Resources.Resx (I think) this can found in your Properties folder in your project file

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7k989cfy(v=vs.80).aspx This link has some information about using Resources

Its better to add the files to the project resource if your going to need them on multiple forms in the project. If they are only going to be required by the current form, you might as well put them in the forms resource file